# NodeJS: Attempt to push to readable throws "Error: not implemented"

Tags: node.js

Why does the following code (saved as `dummy.js`) throw an error? What is the fix?

```
var Stream = require('stream');

var src = new Stream.Readable();

var dest = new Stream();
dest.writable = true;
dest.write = function(data) { console.log("dest:",data); };

["1","2","3"].forEach(function(f) { console.log(f); src.push(f); });

src.pipe(dest);
```

**Execution:**

```
> node dummy.js 
1
2
3

events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: not implemented
    at Readable._read (_stream_readable.js:446:22)
    at Readable.read (_stream_readable.js:320:10)
    at Readable.on (_stream_readable.js:701:14)
    at Readable.pipe (_stream_readable.js:556:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/jay/dummy.js:16:5)
    at (etc.)
```

Answer (score 2):

Push `null` after pushing the array values and before calling `pipe`. Also need to add `dest.end = function(data) {};` after `data.write = ...`.